# R ggplot2 - how to specify different colors for two geom_point

Tags: r

With a data frame like below I'm creating a line plots using `ggplot`

```
df <- data.frame(a=seq(1.1,9.9,1.1), b=seq(0.1,0.9,0.1),
                  c=rev(seq(10.1, 99.9, 11.1)))

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x=names(df)[1]))
p1 <- p1 + geom_line(aes_string(y = names(df)[2] ) ) )
p1 <- p1 + geom_line(aes_string(y = names(df)[3] ) ) )
```

I need to have different colors for the two geom_lines and a legend that shows the colors with names `names(df)[2]` & `names(df)[3]` respectively for first and second lines

How to specify this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this in `base R` (without using any external libraries - `reshape2` is an external library)

```
plot(df$a, df$b, type = "b", col = 2, xlim = range(df$a), 
       ylim = range(c(df$b, df$c)), xlab = "a", ylab ="value")
lines(df$a, df$c, type = "b", col = 3)
legend("topright", legend = names(df)[-1], pch=1, col = 2:3)
```

[image]

---

If we need to use only `ggplot2` and without any other library

```
d1 <- data.frame(a = df$a, variable = names(df)[-1][col(df[-1])], value = unlist(df[-1]))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d1, aes(a, value, col= variable)) + 
                        geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

with dplyr / tidyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -a) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(a, value, col = variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

with base R:

```
library(reshape2)
ggplot(melt(df, id='a'), aes(a, value, col=variable)) + geom_line()
```

without any library (except ggplot2):

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(df$a, df$b, col='b')) +
  geom_line(aes(df$a, df$c, col='c')) +
  xlab('a') + ylab('value')
```

[image]

Comment: looking for a solution without using other libraries.

Comment: Is a solution possible with just ggplot ?

Comment: added a solution with only ggplot and without any other library